# Please explain this program?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, append

I found this program when i was going through a book and I can't understand it. Can anyone explain this in simple terms

```
girls = ['alice', 'bernice', 'clarice']
boys = ['chris', 'arnold', 'bob']
letterGirls = {}
for girl in girls:
    letterGirls.setdefault(girl[0], []).append(girl)
    print [b+'+'+g for b in boys for g in letterGirls[b[0]]]
```

Comment: What, specifically, don't you understand?

Answer (score 0):

```
girls = ['alice', 'bernice', 'clarice']
boys = ['chris', 'arnold', 'bob']
```

`girls` and `boys` are two [lists](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm)

```
`letterGirls = {}`
```

`letterGirls` is a [dictionary](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm)

`setdefault()` method will set `dict_var[key]=default` if key is not already in dict_var (in your case `dict_var` is `letterGirls` )

> **dict_var.setdefault() usage**
>
> `dict-var.setdefault(somekey,[]).append(somevalue)`

In your code

```
letterGirls.setdefault(girl[0], []).append(girl)
```

will make a dictionary of the form

```
{'c': ['clarice'], 'b': ['bernice'], 'a': ['alice']}
```

key is `girl[0]` ie the first letter of name.

There was an indentation problem with your script.Other wise it will cause `Key error` .

It should be

```
girls = ['alice', 'bernice', 'clarice']
boys = ['chris', 'arnold', 'bob']
letterGirls = {}
for girl in girls:
    letterGirls.setdefault(girl[0], []).append(girl)   
print ([b+'+'+g for b in boys for g in letterGirls[b[0]]])
```

your output

```
['chris+clarice', 'arnold+alice', 'bob+bernice']
```

is obatined by taking each item in boys list and finding girl name with same first letter from dictionary letterGirls

Comment: @Faruq Feel free to mark as correct and give an upvote